# Several versions of a single screen according to button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

sorry if the title seems nebulous I didn't know how to give more information with the possible space!

I'm a beginner with WPF, and I'd like to know if it's possible, and if so how, to make a screen that displays different things depending on the button you open it with (I work in MVVM). One exemple of button :

```
    private void BtLock_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        WPFLockPlanning lockPlanning = new WPFLockPlanning();
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(lockPlanning);
        helper.Owner = this.Handle;
        lockPlanning.CmbLock.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        lockPlanning.ShowDialog();            
    }
```

- For example, if I press button 1, I get to screen "WPFLockPlanning" version 1.
- If I press button 2, I get to screen "WPFLockPlanning" version 2 (without 
  radiobox, for exemple).
- On button 3, I arrive on screen "WPFLockPlanning" version 3 (without radiobox and new title, for exemple).

Overall, the three versions of this screen are identical. But little things change (the title, a radio box that disappears,...). The changes don't seem complicated to me (for example, my title property being bind, I can test if button 1 has been clicked, and if so then load the screen title 1 version 1.)

I simply lack the "how" to make the link between the button on the previous screen and retrieve the information.

Thanks !

Comment: Use the [IsVisible-Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isvisible?view=netframework-4.8) of controls to control which controls should be visible

Comment: How about adding a public method to your _"WPFLockPlanning"_ form that allows you to configure the form according to a parameter. Call the method prior to _"lockPlanning.ShowDialog()"_

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
But in both cases, how do I get the information, how do I know that, for example, "X is not visible" if I press button 1 , how do I get the parameter of a button on my screen?
Oh, you editing. But if i add a method in "WPFLockPlanning", it's no more MVVM isn't it ?

Comment: @DennisSchröer: if you read the documentation you gave a link to you will see that IsVisible is a read only property - the property to use to show/hide controls is [Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.visibility?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Sephystos: I am not sure what you are asking when you say "how do I know that X is not visible when I press button 1" - it is up to you to set whether or not X is visible. The _"sender"_ parameter of the click event enables you to determine which button is clicked (or use separate events for each button).

Comment: It's okay, I just confused "isVisible" and "visibility", that's exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: From your new form it will not be easily possible at run time to determine which button click caused the form to be displayed. You need to decide how to do that - you could create a constructor with a parameter - or you could add a property that is set - or you could create a method.

Comment: I edit my main message with "Visibility". Can't I just do it like that?
Or could you maybe give me a short exemple ? Thanks again.

Comment: There are many ways of doing what you want - I have given some examples - the way you have just shown is another way. It is up to you to decide where to add the code to display the controls. With your method - which controls are displayed is decided at time of form creation - this would allow many more than 3 "versions" of a form. If you want to limit the versions of form to 3 - with specific controls shown - then I would have allowed the form itself to handle that via a method or constructor parameter. All of these are design decisions only you can make.